# How to put some random numbers in a matrix of zeros which are also selected randomly?

Tags: python-3.x, random, sparse-matrix

I want to put some random numbers (which have normal distribution) in a matrix of zeros with python. The place of inserting these random numbers also should be random and obey a specific probability measure (e.x.p=0.5).
I can do that with for loop but I want to have an optimized way to increase complexity and time. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy, then check out the following:

- [Generating a matrix of zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)
- [Generating a matrix from the normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html#numpy.random.randn)

It is a little unclear what you mean by "increase complexity and time". Surely you intend to decrease complexity and time.

Unless you are seeking to generate a massive matrix a for loop is probably fine:

```
import random

res = []
p = 0.5
mean = 0
stddev = 1
n = 5

for i in range(0, n):
    res.append([])
    for j in range(0, n):
        if random.random() >= p:
            res[i].append(random.normalvariate(mean, stddev))
        else:
            res[i].append(0)

print(res)
```

Comment: excuse me! I want to decrease complexity and time.

Comment: And I am looking to make massive matrix !

Comment: In that case you’ll want to use numpy or an equivalent library that is optimized. I’m not as familiar with those to help you out with this though